# How to lowecase or uppercase column header in scala spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am seeing warning method `toLowerCase` , is there any a better approach to lowercase column header. Also `df.toDF(df.columns map(_.toLowerCase): _*)` did not work.

I tried:

````
df.select(df.columns.map(x=> col(x).as(x.toLowerCase)):_*).show(false) 
 
warning: Passing an explicit array value to a Scala varargs method is deprecated (since 2.13.0) and will result in a defensive copy; Use the more efficient non-copying ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray or an explicit toIndexedSeq call```
````

Comment: `ds.selectExpr(ds.columns.map(c => c.toLowerCase): _*)` what about this?

Comment: Scala 2.13+ no longer accepts Array as `varargs`.  You can simply convert the Array to another Scala collection, like `df.columns.toSeq.map(_.toLowerCase): _*`.